# Referenceerror: data is undefined

Tags: firefox, sdk

I'm trying to make a firefox addon that uses contentscript to inject a .js file in a certain page. Most of it works but i keep getting this weird error.

main.js

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data = require('sdk/self').data;

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ["http://www.google.com",
            "https://ww.google.com"
           ],
  contentScriptFile: data.url("contentscript.js")
});
```

contentscript.js

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = data.url('jquery.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

setTimeout(function(){
  var d = document.createElement('script');
  d.src = data.url('script.js');
  d.onload = function() {
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  };
  (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(d);
},100)
```

the content of script.js is unrelevant, because it doesn't even get executed. The error is in contentscript:2:1 Referenceerror: data is undefined.

Keep in mind it needs to be done this way, the script needs to be able to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access data.url from the content script, you can only do that from main.js. You could pass the file path and name of the script from main in contentScriptOptions.

Also I'm not sure what you're intending to use this for but if you do `include: ["https://www.google.com"]` then page-mod will only work on https://www.google.com. `include: "[*]"` allows all websites etc.